# r - jsonlite add carriage returns at end of json array "parent elements"

Tags: json, r, carriage-return, jsonlite

I am new to manipulating json arrays in R. When I write a json array using R package jsonlite to a .json file using the below code, I get the entire json array printed on the first line of that file (reg is a data.frame).

```
rownames(reg) <- NULL
write(toJSON(reg), file = "test.json")
```

I would like to be able to add a carriage return "\n" at the end of each major ("parent") element in the nested hierarchy, so instead it looks like the below:

```
[{"val":"ID1","prop":{"Sub":{"val":"foo"}},
{"val":"ID2","prop":{"Sub":{"val":"bar"}}]
```

instead of:

```
[{"val":"ID1","prop":{"Sub":{"val":"foo"}},{"val":"ID2","prop":{"Sub":{"val":"bar"}}]
```

Can anyone help me?

**Note:** I don't want the "pretty" layout. I want one line per parent element/all children properties.

Here is an example data.frame

```
reg <- data.frame(value=c("ID1", "ID2", "ID3"), properties.Subject.value=c("http://example.org/ID1", "http://example.org/ID2", "http://example.org/ID3"), properties.Subject.properties.value=c("http://example.org/xID1", "http://example.org/xID2", "http://example.org/xID3"))
```

> ```
> value    properties.Subject.value  properties.Subject.properties.value
> ID1      http://example.org/ID1    http://example.org/xID1
> ID2      http://example.org/ID2    http://example.org/xID2
> ID3      http://example.org/ID3    http://example.org/xID3
> ```

Comment: In `?write` it says there is a sep argument. You might try adding `sep="\n"`, but I am not sure it will work.

Comment: I overlooked your requirement, that you don't want pretty layout. Hence deleted answer. can you add an example dataframe ?

Comment: Added data frame example!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your requirements of new line I think `stream_out` should work.

```
require(jsonlite)
output <- file("test.json")
stream_out(head(mtcars), con = output, verbose = TRUE)
```

output

```
{"mpg":21,"cyl":6,"disp":160,"hp":110,"drat":3.9,"wt":2.62,"qsec":16.46,"vs":0,"am":1,"gear":4,"carb":4,"_row":"Mazda RX4"}
{"mpg":21,"cyl":6,"disp":160,"hp":110,"drat":3.9,"wt":2.875,"qsec":17.02,"vs":0,"am":1,"gear":4,"carb":4,"_row":"Mazda RX4 Wag"}
{"mpg":22.8,"cyl":4,"disp":108,"hp":93,"drat":3.85,"wt":2.32,"qsec":18.61,"vs":1,"am":1,"gear":4,"carb":1,"_row":"Datsun 710"}
{"mpg":21.4,"cyl":6,"disp":258,"hp":110,"drat":3.08,"wt":3.215,"qsec":19.44,"vs":1,"am":0,"gear":3,"carb":1,"_row":"Hornet 4 Drive"}
{"mpg":18.7,"cyl":8,"disp":360,"hp":175,"drat":3.15,"wt":3.44,"qsec":17.02,"vs":0,"am":0,"gear":3,"carb":2,"_row":"Hornet Sportabout"}
{"mpg":18.1,"cyl":6,"disp":225,"hp":105,"drat":2.76,"wt":3.46,"qsec":20.22,"vs":1,"am":0,"gear":3,"carb":1,"_row":"Valiant"}
```

`?stream_out`

> Because parsing huge JSON strings is difficult and inefficient, JSON streaming is done using lines of minified JSON records, a.k.a. ndjson. This is pretty standard: JSON databases such as dat or MongoDB use the same format to import/export datasets. Note that this means that the total stream combined is not valid JSON itself; only the individual lines are. Also note that because line-breaks are used as separators, prettified JSON is not permitted: the JSON lines must be minified. In this respect, the format is a bit different from fromJSON and toJSON where all lines are part of a single JSON structure with optional line breaks.